# how to use date_query arguments in wp comment list in a bash script

Tags: wordpress, bash, nagios

I would like to create a bash script to count number of comments in wordpress, 4 hours ago.

It will use in a nagios plugins

I would like using "`wp comment list`" or some `wp cli` command for the wordpress request

I will use the `date` bash command to interact with the wp cli.

I try to have things like

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date --date="4 hour ago" '%Y-%m-%d %T')

nbr_comment=$(wp comment list --patch=FULL/PATH/TO/wordpress --status=approve "--date_query=after $now" --format=count);
```

echo -e "nbr_comment\n$now"

my problem, now, is to find the correct syntax in date_query arguments.

The commands stil return number of whole comments instead of the number of comments in last  4 hours.

sources : wp comment list

--date_query refers on WP_Date_Query

thank you for your help

Comment: Those asterisks around the `--date_query` argument will glob expand file names the way it is written.

Comment: Are you trying to bold that with mark-up?  This will not work inside of a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of splitting and quoting. When you assign the variable `$now`, you are running the following command in a command substitution:

```
date --date="4 hour ago" +%Y-%m-%d %T
```

This will complain about an extra operand (`%T`).  The arguments for this command are broken down this way:

```
--date="4 hour ago" # Optional argument
+%Y-%m-%d           # Output format
%T                  # Extra operand
```

Group your output format with quoting to fix this:

```
date --date="4 hour ago" '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
# With the variable assignment
now=$(date --date="4 hour ago" '+%Y-%m-%d %T')
```

Your `wp` command also suffers from the same issue in the `date_query` argument.  (I'm going to assume that the asterisks were an attempt at mark-up within a code block.)  The argument looks like this:

```
--date_query='after'$now
```

If we assume the value of `$now` is 2020-02-24 07:00:00, the arguments will be split like this:

```
--date_query=after2020-02-24 
07:00:00
```

You will need to quote this in order to avoid splitting.  To make it simple, I would suggest using double quotes on the entire string (I also added a space after the word after):

```
"--date_query=after $now"
```

**Edit:**  In the future, try using [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net), or you can download a local version to your machine.  Shellcheck would have caught this mistake for you.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your answer and precision.

sorry for the date command, the really code was :

```
date --date="4 hour ago" +%T-%m-%d\ %T
```

but your command have the same result.

for the WP command I did not find the way to have my main result. yes, I was trying to highlited the `--date_query` command.

anyway, when I put the command like you suggest :

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date --date="4 hour ago" '+%Y-%m-%d %T')

nbr=$(wp comment list --path=/var/www/wordpress "--date_query=after $now" --format=count);

echo -e "$nbr\n$now"
```

it counts all the comments instead of the last four hours.

Comment: I would add this to the question using the "edit" button instead of posting as an answer.